# How to implement: interface MySortedCollection<T extends Comparable<T>>

Tags: java, interface, comparable

I have the following interface:

```
interface MySortedCollection<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    boolean isElement(T t);
    void insert(T t);
    void printSorted();
}
```

I tried to use the AVLTree to implement the interface:

```
public class AVLTree<T> implements MySortedCollection{

  private AVLNode<T> tree=null;

  public AVLTree (){
  } 

  public boolean isElement(T t){

  }


  public void insert(T t){
    if(tree==null){
      tree= new AVLNode<T>(t);
    }
  }

  public void printSorted(){}

}
```

But I got the error:

```
error: AVLTree is not abstract and does not override abstract
method insert(Comparable) in MySortedCollection 
public class AVLTree<T> implements MySortedCollection{
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
public class AVLTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements MySortedCollection<T> {
}
```

Make sure that AVLNode class has a similar signature

```
public class AVLNode<T extends Comparable<T>> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

shoudl be

```
public class AVLTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements MySortedCollection<T> {
```